in Cmd get user Org Unit and strip all but org unit name and pass to a variable
I want to use the command prompt to find what Organizational Unit the current user belongs to, and then store ONLY the value of the Organizational Units name into a variable called MyOu (It can be any variable name really though), and then echo the value of MyOu.
For example, if we use the command
whoami /fqdn
I get the following output
CN=Joseph Sanders,OU=IT Staff,DC=hpaba,DC=local
From that output I want the data in variable
MyOu
to be.....
IT Staff
So that if I use echo MyOu the output would be: IT Staff
How can I accomplish this from the cmd prompt?
Once I get this working, it will end up going in a batch file. Thanks in advance!
EDIT: I was told to edit the question because it might have been answered here: split string using Batch script, however, I do not agree my question has been answered, becuase the eaxmples are not the same. In that example given, the user was setting a value and using data from a CSV file (at leat it looks like that to me), and I am using data pulled from the current logged in user (which can change based on who is logged in) as opposed to static data.
Also, the example given as supposedly answering my question does not take into account that the value I am working with and trying to "split" has Equal signs, spaces, and commas. I am only wanting to keep the data after OU= but before ,DC=hpaba,DC=local.
In other words, when I run command: whoami /fqdn I get the following result:
CN=Joseph Sanders,OU=IT Staff,DC=hpaba,DC=local
I want ONLY the following: IT Staff to be stored in the variable MyOu but the example that was given as a possible duplicate solution does not address this complicated scenario.

I answered your question in the comment section of your initial submission, so that you could clearly see how the duplicate is such. The least you could have done was to try it before submitting a duplicate of the same question! And the version submitted by Mofi, which may work better for you, is simply the same method, with an additional step. Your question is still a duplicate, despite your insistance that it isn't.

Please open a command prompt window, run first help, next whoami /?, then for /? and last set /? and read each output help. There are five lines needed: 1. set "MyOU=" 2. for /F "delims=" %%G in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\whoami.exe /FQDN 2^>nul') do set "MyOU=%%G" 3. if not defined MyOU exit /B (or goto Label) 4. set "MyOU=%MyOU:*,OU=%" 5. for /F "delims=," %%G in ("%MyOU%") do set "MyOU%%G". This code does not work on organizational unit containing one or more commas.

From this stack overflow post
whoami /fqdn | sed 's/.*OU=\(.*\),.*/\1/'

This should get you the correct output, which you can use to set a variable.

the question is explicitly about ´cmd/batch`, not bash

@Zico Thank you, when I try that i get 'sed' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Ah, I see. I assume you are on a Windows CMD prompt right?

@Zico, Yes that is correct.

If you are OK installing CLI tools, cygwin has sed included. unxutils is another option. If you don't want to install additional tools, we can look for an alternative.

@Zico, Thanks, I would rather not just to keep from adding even more things to this. This will eventually go into a bat file and will be used to determine what OU the current signed in user belongs to.

I did figur eout that the following command seems to give me the results I desire, while testing against my own account, but I am not sure that it will work for users who are in a different OU. Here is the command I came up with that appears to work for me, at the moment:  for /F "tokens=2 delims=," %G in ('whoami /fqdn ^| find "OU="') do for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %H in ("%G") do SET MyOu=%H
